# What is a wedged through tenon and how is it used?

Tags: joinery, terminology, knockdown

What is a wedged through tenon and how is it constructed? How is it different than a "standard" mortise and tenon? When should it be used?

Comment: Note that this a through tenon with a wedge, not a tenon that gets wedged through.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is where you mortise right through the timber, and hammer wedges into the joint from the other side, in order to mechanically wedge the tenon into the joint. You still use glue as you normally would.

See [here](http://www.craftsmanspace.com/knowledge/wedged-tenon-and-mortise-joint.html) for examples.

I'll include the images here for future reference:

Outer wedged:
[image: outer wedged through tenon]

Inner wedged:
[image: inner wedged through tenon]

They're typically used when making doors, and are good because they form a good strong joint, and they look nice from the front (better than a mitre joint), however they're not all that nice to look at from the edges, and the timber of the mortised piece can shrink or swell around the tenoned end or the wedges and leave them sunken in or sticking proud after some time. You'll also need to play around a bit with the width of the tenon vs the mortise and the taper angle of the wedges etc. the first time you make one, to get it just right.

Note that (as with just about any type of joint) there are many variations for different situations. See [here](http://www.craftsmanspace.com/knowledge/mortise-and-tenon-woodworking-joints.html) for many more examples. Probably the most important and commonly used variation is the "haunched" joint which is where you cut part of the tenon away, to space it away from a corner (e.g. the top or bottom of a door leaf):

[image: haunched wedged mortise and tenon joint]

Comment: If you want to understand just how strong these wedged tenons are, note that this is how axe heads, hammer heads, sledge heads, etc have been held onto their handles for centuries.

Answer (score 4):

Adding to WhatEvil posted, there is another type of wedged through tenon, more precisely referred to as a wedged tusk tenon or a tusk tenon. This one is primarily used for knockdown construction. It has many of the same strengths as other mortise and tenon joinery but doesn't use glue.  The "pin" (tusk) length also helps a little to prevent racking.

Sometimes there is a double pin, where the pins are horizontal and you use one from each side to hold the joint in place.

[image: Wedged tusk tenon]

Comment: I've seen these referred to as "tusk" tenions. They can be made fancier by shaping the top of the wedge, if desired.

Comment: This is more precisely called a wedged tusk tenon. Personally I'd call it that or a tusk tenon rather than a wedged tenon, simply because it leaves less room for confusion. Even though Fine Woodworking has published at least one article classifying it as a type of wedged tenon, their article on how to make a wedged tenon doesn't demonstrate how to make a wedged tusk tenon.

Comment: @rob, well having both in this answer can help those that might be confused between the two.  I didn't know there were different names

Comment: @keshlam added it to my answer

Comment: @bowlturner I apologize if my comment sounded overly critical. As soon as I saw the question I expected to see answers including both the "end grain" wedged tenon and the tusk tenon. There is a lot of confusion and even disagreement about woodworking terminology, and I think the best thing we can do is to point out and encourage use of a more precise term whenever someone is aware of one.

Comment: @rob I didn't take it as a negative against me.  I tried adding in the terminology to my answer, If you think it could be clearer, feel free to make another edit.

Comment: I think the consensus appears to be that WhatEvil's answer is the definition of a wedged through tenon. Yet another instance of ambiguous woodworking terminology, it seems.

Comment: I've mentioned in other answers and comments - it seems for just about every joint you can think of, there's no universal agreement on what to call it! I went with my answer because I think that type of wedged through tenon is the more commonly used one, but yes this is also a type of wedged through tenon.